# MongoDB : Query very slow with sort and group

Tags: mongodb

I have a flat structure of document in my mongodb cluster (3 shared), the number of documents is about 450 000 000.

Here are the main fields of the document :

OriginCity
DestinationCity
DepartureDateDate
ReturnDateDate
TotalPriceADT

I need to find all the best price (TotalPriceADT) for the next 6 months per DestinationCity from a specific OriginCity (ex : PAR).

Here is my query :

```
db.cache_00001.aggregate(
[
    { 
        $match: {
            "OriginCity": "PAR",
            $and: 
            [ 
                {DepartureDateDate: {$gt: new ISODate("2019-02-12T00:00:00.000Z")}},
                {DepartureDateDate: {$lt: new ISODate("2019-08-12T00:00:00.000Z")}},
            ]
        },
    },
    {
        "$sort": { "TotalPriceADT": 1}
    }, 
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 
            {
                "DestinationCity": "$DestinationCity",
            },
            "Propositions": 
            {
                "$first": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }

],
{ 
    allowDiskUse: true,
})
```

The query works, I got the right results, the problem is the response time, it's very very slow. I created an compound index with OriginCity & DepartureDateDate.

Could you tell me how I can improve the query to get a better response time? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Jérome.

Comment: If you're sorting by a key, you almost always will want it to be part of your compound index so that mongo doesn't have to calculate the sort. I'd guess that adding the key you're grouping by might help as well, but I think that most of the benefit will come from adding that sort key

Comment: Hi Willis, Thanks for your comment, I have created a compound index with OriginCity, DepartureDateDate, TotalPriceADT, unfortunately the performances are the same...

db.cache_00001.createIndex(
    {
        OriginCity: 1,
        DepartureDateDate: 1,
        TotalPriceADT:1
    },
    {
        name: "OriginCityDepartureDateDateTotalPriceADTIndex",
        background: true
    }
)

Comment: Could you share an explain for one of these slow queries? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-explain-option